# How to access and read the values of child objects of an object?

Tags: java, android, arrays, loops

Here is how I am constructing an Object inside a method:

//right after creating the class

```
public static ArrayList<Object> old_devicelist = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

//inside a method

```
Date date = new Date();
long time = date.getTime();
Integer opened = 0;
String deviceId = "";
String dev_rssi = "";
Object[] MyObject = new Object[]{time, opened, deviceId, dev_rssi};

old_devicelist.add(MyObject);
```

Now, I would like to loop through that ArrayList and access some elements (note that deviceId might at some point contain an object and I would like to access id field of it) inside it, then I would like to use them like this, for ex. :

```
if(device.id == 33){

//do something...

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an array with type Object and then you're storing these object arrays into a list. This makes it hard to retrieve the information later.

Consider this instead:

```
public static List<Device> DEVICES = new ArrayList<>();

class Device {
  Date date;
  long time;
  Integer opened;
  String deviceId;
  String deviceRssi

  Device(Date date, Integer opened, String deviceId, String deviceRssi) {
    this.date = date;
    this.time = date.getTime();
    this.opened = opened;
    this.deviceId = deviceId;
    this.deviceRssi = deviceRssi;
  }
}

Device first = new Device(
  new Date(),
  0,
  "",
  "");

DEVICES.add(first);
System.out.println(DEVICES.get(0).deviceId);
...
for (Device device : DEVICES) {
  if (device.deviceId.equals("33)) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I'd recommend not using too many static/global variables and reading about the Java Naming Convention.

Comment: One more thing, deviceId is in fact an object so how can I actually access it?

Comment: and this does not print anything: System.out.println(OLD_DEVICES.get(0).device);

Comment: How you can access deviceId? Using the object-Field. See here for a detailed discussion: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html

Comment: System.out.println(OLD_DEVICES.get(0).device); will only print something if you implement a toString() method in Device. See here: https://www.javatpoint.com/understanding-toString()-method

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should create new class instead of using Object.

```
public class DeviceSpecification {  //or any other name
    long time;
    Integer opened;
    String deviceId;
    String dev_rssi;

    public DeviceSpecification(long time, Integer opened, String deviceId, String dev_rssi) {
        this.time = time;
        this.opened = opened;
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
        this.dev_rssi = dev_rssi;
    }
}
```

Create a list with specific type:

```
public static List<DeviceSpecification> oldDeviceCollection = new ArrayList<>();
```

Create an instance of a class

```
DeviceSpecification device = new DeviceSpecification(new Date().getTime(), 0, "", "")
```

Add the instance to a list

```
oldDeviceCollection.add(device);
```

Use it in query - we can use streams from Java 8

```
oldDeviceCollection.stream()
   .forEach( 
     device -> {
       if(device.id.equals("33")) {
         // do something
      }
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your Arraylist takes Objects and you are trying to add an Object array so if your goal is to keep object arrays with the device_id you should change your Arraylist to

```
public static ArrayList<Object[]> old_devicelist = new ArrayList();
```

Taking that in mind you can access any deviceid by typing

```
old_devicelist.get(i)[2]
```

where i is the element you want and 2 because you have setted `device_id` to be the 3rd element of your Object array!
Hope this helps!